# how to place tikzpicture from left edge of paper

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

i'm using tikz to draw a diagram. But i meet the problem: latex place the tikzpicture with a distant to left edge of paper and its too large that goes over right edge. Like the picture below shows, theres still plenty of space at left corner, and right part of picture already gose out of page. I have done nothing than simply write:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[square/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4}]
     %draw something large here
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
```

how can i place it correctly?

the compilable code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/H2NGYtKV
Or by Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/hhxjmxdkvscg
[image]

Comment: You  have certainly done more that this, because the code you posted does not compile.

Comment: well, if u insist to see the whole code, here it is: https://pastebin.com/H2NGYtKV

Comment: The `tikzpicture` is too large to fit within `\textwidth`. The white margin on the left is the usual document margin. There is no `a3paper` option for the `article` class. See the `*.log` file.

Comment: so how can i adjust it? other than use resizebox (what i currently use)

Comment: ok... i used geometry to adjust margin  \geometry{
 a3paper,
 left=2mm,
 top=20mm,
}
 and the problem is resolved

Comment: If you also post that solution as an answer (rather than a comment) then it will be readily visible for people with similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i have solved it myself by using geometry package and combined it with resizebox:

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman,landscape]{article}
...
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
         left=2mm,
         top=20mm,
         right=2mm,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[square/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4}]
         %% codes gose here
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As the result, it uses the full space from left edge to right edge.

The compilable Code can be find here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/hhxjmxdkvscg

[image]